# java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, ssl

I have the following code:

```
package daoImp;

import java.util.List;

import javapns.Push;
import javapns.communication.exceptions.KeystoreException;
import javapns.notification.PushedNotification;
import javapns.notification.ResponsePacket;
import org.json.JSONException;
import com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.CommunicationException;

public class Notification {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            new Notification().sendMessageToAPN();
        } catch (CommunicationException | KeystoreException | JSONException
                | javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessageToAPN() throws CommunicationException,
            KeystoreException, JSONException,
            javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException {
        String regId1 = "6f9d340ab4d0f81206f7d8c1ab7b8994d90d139e0d1d2b99999b02887e60d54f";
        List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.alert("hello","C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/security/gameover.p12", "gameover",
                false, regId1);
        for (PushedNotification notification : notifications) {
            if (notification.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Push notification sent successfully to: " + notification.getDevice().getToken());

            } else {
                String invalidToken = notification.getDevice().getToken();
                System.err.println("Invalid Token " + invalidToken);

                System.out.println(" The problem was");
                Exception theProblem = notification.getException();
                theProblem.printStackTrace();

                ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = notification.getResponse();
                if (theErrorResponse != null) {
                    System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following exception message: `handshake to ssl failed as connection to remote host failed during handshake`.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (javapns.notification.Payload).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Invalid Token 6f9d340ab4d0f81206f7d8c1ab7b6774d90d139e0d1d2b58599b02887e60d54f
 The problem was
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:402)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:350)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:320)
    at javapns.Push.sendPayload(Push.java:177)
    at javapns.Push.alert(Push.java:47)
    at daoImp.Notification.sendMessageToAPN(Notification.java:27)
    at daoImp.Notification.main(Notification.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

I don't know why I'm getting this message.

Answer (score 9):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

Above `Exception` is a generic exception we get in the client if there is any of below scenario:

- If Server and Client support different version of TLS e.g. server
  support TLS2 while Client support only TLS1. This issue can be resolved by setting below property in Client side :

> `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");`

- If the server is not able to validate the certificate chain of the client, then also it will close the conection.

> Certificate chain    qtp510727907-31, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain    %%
>   Invalidated:  [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
>   qtp510727907-31, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description =
>   bad_certificate    qtp510727907-31, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
>   main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1    qtp510727907-31,
>   fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain

To know the exact cause of failure, we need to enable `-Djavax.net.debug=all` while executing the client call towards the server.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because of Internet connection problem/poor internet connection.
Please check your internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing your certificates.

You can generate them using the InstallCerts app. (http://miteff.com/install-cert)

or http://opentox.ntua.gr/blog/77-ssl-certificates

Once you get your certificate, you need to put it under your security directory within your jdk home, for example:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security

**Hope this resolves your issue**