# java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly with FTPS server connection

Tags: sslhandshakeexception

Following exception is thrown while connecting to FTPS server :
java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Server certificate is added in jre/lib/security/cacerts.
Tried with JDK8 and JDK11, but it fails with same exception.

How to fix this issue.

javax.net.debug log (ServerHelloDone onwards) : __________________________________

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 178, 153, 201, 133, 162, 82, 146, 241, 49, 176, 247, 206, 20, 125, 91, 178, 230, 144, 68, 55, 50, 206, 9, 115, 136, 61, 103, 201, 44, 57, 168, 54, 247, 56, 156, 160, 242, 47, 107, 79, 46, 240, 67, 59, 190, 97, 8, 204, 68, 102, 129, 40, 76, 83, 132, 129, 199, 59, 101, 104, 76, 231, 104, 49 }
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 70
0000: 10 00 00 42 41 04 B2 99   C9 85 A2 52 92 F1 31 B0  ...BA......R..1.
0010: F7 CE 14 7D 5B B2 E6 90   44 37 32 CE 09 73 88 3D  ....[...D72..s.=
0020: 67 C9 2C 39 A8 36 F7 38   9C A0 F2 2F 6B 4F 2E F0  g.,9.6.8.../kO..
0030: 43 3B BE 61 08 CC 44 66   81 28 4C 53 84 81 C7 3B  C;.a..Df.(LS...;
0040: 65 68 4C E7 68 31                                  ehL.h1
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
[Raw write]: length = 75
0000: 16 03 03 00 46 10 00 00   42 41 04 B2 99 C9 85 A2  ....F...BA......
0010: 52 92 F1 31 B0 F7 CE 14   7D 5B B2 E6 90 44 37 32  R..1.....[...D72
0020: CE 09 73 88 3D 67 C9 2C   39 A8 36 F7 38 9C A0 F2  ..s.=g.,9.6.8...
0030: 2F 6B 4F 2E F0 43 3B BE   61 08 CC 44 66 81 28 4C  /kO..C;.a..Df.(L
0040: 53 84 81 C7 3B 65 68 4C   E7 68 31                 S...;ehL.h1
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 31 27 F1 39 95 53 C7 13   68 FB EB 5F A8 30 EE B4  1'.9.S..h.._.0..
0010: 70 AB 88 5A BE EB E7 E2   AC 69 F3 FA 7A DE B3 F4  p..Z.....i..z...
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 62 30 27 77 A0 7F 32 32   D2 1B F0 CB C9 84 B5 E7  b0'w..22........
0010: 64 82 11 26 E5 59 97 03   09 95 E1 64 16 52 39 F0  d..&.Y.....d.R9.
Server Nonce:
0000: 2B E5 19 7C 4C 91 7F CE   11 08 69 36 9D 23 0D BB  +...L.....i6.#..
0010: 04 92 7D 14 12 03 DC 68   83 7C 28 4E 9F B3 B3 C0  .......h..(N....
Master Secret:
0000: 0E 53 1D D1 5D 82 EF 7C   DC B7 41 F2 31 29 19 61  .S..].....A.1).a
0010: B0 92 F1 23 38 BB C7 4D   59 20 8F 4C 0F 50 71 73  ...#8..MY .L.Pqs
0020: FB DE A5 25 F4 7C BD 00   41 61 15 FA C9 4F 3E C4  ...%....Aa...O>.
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: F3 04 24 61 15 44 58 B3   EF 15 CF 6F A5 39 BF BF  ..$a.DX....o.9..
0010: FC CA 5D 36 D6 1A DA AF   1E 77 A3 86 2F 66 23 8C  ..]6.....w../f#.
0020: BE 6C 8B 82 F3 00 20 41   82 19 EA 07 7F 91 28 66  .l.... A......(f
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: E8 0E AA 00 6F 1A 9C 7A   2D 09 34 A1 F4 AA 8D 9C  ....o..z-.4.....
0010: D9 39 81 D3 37 79 C5 D6   D9 DD BB B6 60 05 CC 90  .9..7y......`...
0020: BF 13 AC 9D 28 2E 8E 27   DF 70 3A D2 51 8F 85 43  ....(..'.p:.Q..C
Client write key:
0000: C0 92 A3 06 91 2D BC DF   31 23 FD 02 9A ED BD 27  .....-..1#.....'
0010: 06 E8 F6 1D F7 1F B0 AC   D1 6E DE 1A 34 85 BC F9  .........n..4...
Server write key:
0000: D4 3D 88 0E 35 0D 17 9D   CC 9D 03 DE FD 55 69 67  .=..5........Uig
0010: 05 02 B9 FC E7 68 58 E9   F1 95 2E B5 A1 13 6C BC  .....hX.......l.
... no IV derived for this protocol
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 03 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 115, 94, 17, 134, 75, 180, 250, 50, 81, 178, 155, 185 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 73 5E 11 86   4B B4 FA 32 51 B2 9B B9  ....s^..K..2Q...
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 96
0000: 49 0C AE FE DE B7 1F 2A   A6 96 37 B5 A8 1F A0 E0  I......*..7.....
0010: 14 00 00 0C 73 5E 11 86   4B B4 FA 32 51 B2 9B B9  ....s^..K..2Q...
0020: 2E A7 FB 7F 53 04 09 90   FD 99 44 2D 35 C4 84 33  ....S.....D-5..3
0030: 7C 37 5A A5 FD 01 15 0B   0B AE EC F7 AA 79 CC 41  .7Z..........y.A
0040: 3B E0 16 9C FE D8 0C 66   57 57 FC EC 84 7F 69 EE  ;......fWW....i.
0050: 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F   0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F  ................
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 96
[Raw write]: length = 101
0000: 16 03 03 00 60 DE 4D 5C   6E 9B D5 16 10 96 70 8F  ....`.M\n.....p.
0010: 8B CD AA 50 86 83 5C 6C   C2 AC A8 4D CD BA 79 03  ...P..\l...M..y.
0020: 27 1E AC F3 82 A7 1A C0   0B 33 1D 37 7A C3 7C 9D  '........3.7z...
0030: E2 46 6D 95 87 3B 7A 98   7B 31 1A AE 17 E4 70 C6  .Fm..;z..1....p.
0040: 11 FD A2 33 65 9E EC B3   5E 89 64 32 E1 5E 8F 52  ...3e...^.d2.^.R
0050: 0B D2 3B 5B 3F D9 62 F4   79 31 19 38 0B 8C 99 32  ..;[?.b.y1.8...2
0060: 56 DE F6 43 F4                                     V..C.
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 80
0000: 94 B4 1E B3 29 30 18 E7   E1 F3 D9 0B D5 54 B0 96  ....)0.......T..
0010: 02 28 F1 86 BA 9D 57 52   1F B6 75 17 8A 7F DD 0C  .(....WR..u.....
0020: D2 ED 3A 0B 41 2F D0 4A   43 C0 9F C3 BD 46 08 D5  ..:.A/.JC....F..
0030: 4C 66 3F 6C EC 65 C2 38   B0 8F EA B5 DE 62 52 2A  Lf?l.e.8.....bR*
0040: 96 09 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D   0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D 0D  ................
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 80
[Raw write]: length = 85
0000: 15 03 03 00 50 38 37 70   6C E6 7E 07 32 2A 6B 0E  ....P87pl...2*k.
0010: A2 EB C6 DB 1F D6 A1 BB   09 DC 26 29 C5 E9 94 54  ..........&)...T
0020: 2D 80 DE DA FE 2D 45 C8   95 E8 7E 40 A3 25 3A 9E  -....-E....@.%:.
0030: 09 A2 0D 24 89 FD 74 81   E3 33 C8 4D 05 36 C1 42  ...$..t..3.M.6.B
0040: 7B D2 21 C5 C7 93 69 7F   0E A3 2B F0 46 91 BB B2  ..!...i...+.F...
0050: 78 22 F2 98 84                                     x"...
main, called closeSocket()
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFolderException: Could not list the contents of "ftps://dadbftp.allero.org:990/Results" because it is not a folder.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:492)
    at A1.listRemoteFileNames(A1.java:120)
    at A1.test(A1.java:51)
    at A1.main(A1.java:144)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._openDataConnection_(FTPSClient.java:639)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:711)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2255)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2390)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2651)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFilesInDirectory(FTPClientWrapper.java:198)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFiles(FTPClientWrapper.java:192)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:241)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildFile(FtpFileObject.java:470)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.setFTPFile(FtpFileObject.java:634)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetType(FtpFileObject.java:367)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:488)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    ... 18 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Have you tried these links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245796/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232889/java-1-8-and-tomcat-6-0-53-caused-by-java-io-eofexception-ssl-peer-shut-down-i

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628037/java-io-eofexception-ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly